# Открытие формы по нажатию F1

Tags: c#, winforms, справка

[image]

Хочу открывать новую форму по нажатию клавиши <kbd>F1</kbd>, чтобы получалось примерно как на картинке или тут без chm не обойтись?

```
private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
{
    Form helpForm = new Form();
    helpForm.ShowDialog();
}
```

Вот это не срабатывает.

Comment: а где етот ивент хендлер висит то ?)

Comment: а и действительно, где... х)

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, но я курица и просто не повесила хендлер на форму х)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private void Form1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
{
    using (var helpForm = new Form2())
    {
        helpForm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание, что `new Form2()`(в зависимости от названия вашей формы) а не `new Form()`.

Answer (score 3):

[источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951496/how-do-i-capture-keys-f1-regardless-of-the-focused-control-on-a-form)

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.F1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You pressed the F1 key");
        return true;    // indicate that you handled this keystroke
    }

    // Call the base class
    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: `Ctrl + K` на выделенном коде уберет ненужные отступы

Comment: спасибо, постараюсь запомнить